# Scifi horror book where nuclear war literally causes Hell on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I believe it was published in the 2000s. Book starts off with a woman who gets to interview the president of the United States. While she is at the White House, Russia launches a bunch of nukes. The White House has a safe room that gets launched into space. Eventually the safe room lands. Earth has been turned into Hell. The survivors try to survive. Those who repent are saved. Book ends with woman failing to repent, and ends up chasing the person she loves, to murder them over and over again.

Comment: Is this a sort of Christian science fiction? There is a subgenre of films and books directed at evangelicals -- do you think this was such a book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Torment](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9662481-torment) by Jeremy Bishop.

[image: Torment]

> Small town reporter, Mia Durante, finds herself having brunch with the President of the United States on the day civilization comes to an end. An electromagnetic pulse blinds the U.S. Cars crash. Planes fall. Chaos reigns. Power is restored within minutes, but it's already too late. Russian nukes are falling. U.S. allies around the world are all ready wiped out. The United States will cease to exist inside of five minutes.
>
> After giving the order to launch a full-scale retaliation, dooming the planet, the president, White House staff, Secret Service and those lucky enough to be visiting the white house, are whisked below ground where they board several Earth Escape Pods. As the EEPs launch into Earth orbit, missiles descend.
>
> Less than forty survive the end of the world. When they return, they're greeted by survivors of a different sort. The bloodbath that follows leaves Durante and nine other survivors on the run. They find themselves fighting for survival in a world in which only torment remains and where death is the only escape.

The book ends with Mia hunting her fiancée Matt and ripping his intestines out with her bare hands:

> “No,” she said, looking down. Matt’s stomach was open. His guts were in her hands. He screamed again and she realized her hands were yanking at his insides, eviscerating the fiancé she’d betrayed.
>
> “I’m sorry,” she screamed turning her head to the sky. “Make it stop! God, make it stop!”
>
> But she didn’t stop until Matt’s body stopped moving and his own screams of pain faded. Then she was up and moving. She spotted several other killers and headed for them. She didn’t want to be with them. She didn’t want to hear their voices mixed with hers, but her body, and its actions, were not hers to control anymore.
>
> “I wasn’t ready,” she screamed, her voice going hoarse. “I wasn’t ready!”
>
> A shuffling sound turned her around. Matt was there, alive again, pulling his organs back together. He saw her attention and shouted, “No!”
>
> But she was already running toward him, arms outstretched, fingers locked like claws.

Comment: This is it. Thank you!